# Cannot build C# files using msbuild

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

I am creating an MVC C# application and I am using msbuild to build the files to the server.  I can build every file in the project except for C# files.  I recieve no error, they just do not copy to the server. This is my first MVC application, I have been developing classic asp applications before this and never had this issue. Has anyone ever had similar issues?

Comment: How are you building? Maybe you're just building a "build only, don't deploy" target...

Comment: The C# files aren't supposed to end up on the server.

Comment: The cs files get compiled into the .dll.  (a different way of stating what SLaks just said)

Comment: Thanks guys! I was unclear on how the project is built. I did not have the .dll checked in.

Comment: Uh, you do NOT want to check in the dll.  The dll is output and shouldn't be checked in to source control.  When you build a web project, content pages are propagated to their respective folders while the .cs is compiled into a .dll that is placed in the /bin/ folder.